# need a confirmation text to appear on email submission

Tags: ajax, email

With help of other relevant posts here, I have put together a code which allows the users to send me a list of selected posts via e-mail and it is working fine.

Now, I would like a confirmation text eg. 'THANK YOU' appear to the user, once user has clicked the "send email" button. This could appear below the submit button and could have a class so that I could make it a bit pretty using css. I hope this can be achieved with appropriate changes in my codes. Please suggest a correction.

**UPDATED** : **Now my javascript looks like this :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#sendEmail').click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/email.php',
                 data: { content: $('#email-data').html()},
                 success:function(data) {
                        alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
                }        
           });
     });
});
</script>
```

**and my HTML looks like this :**

```
<div id="email-data">
    <div id="content">
        some php generated content
    </div>
</div>
<a id="sendEmail"> SEND EMAIL</a>
```

**my email.php looks like this**

```
<?php

  $to = "someone@somemail.com";
  $subject = "FROM WEBSITE";
  $message = $_POST['content'];
  $headers = "From: company <someotherguy@somecompany.in>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: anyone up for some help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a Success callback to your Ajax function:

```
     $('#sendEmail').click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'www.example.com/email.php',
                 data: { content: $('#email-data').html()},
                 success:  function(data) {
                 //data variable can be used if your ajax call returns something
                     do_stuff_here();
                 }
             });
          });
```

In your case, you could do something like

```
success:  function() {
    $('body').append('<div class="success">Success!</div>');
}
```

However, is there a reason you don't want to use a  and the .submit() method?
(http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Also, don't forget to validate :)

Comment: Thanks for your time. You put me in the right direction and the job is done. Thank You.